# Bash script/gcc - sync with environmental variables and gnome-terminal doesn't work

Tags: bash, gcc, environment-variables, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to use an environment variable to synchronize several processes.  I see the bash script set the RUN_NOW variable to 1 but the C script never sees it and stays in the infinite loop.

Also, any ideas why the gnome-terminal lines in the bash script don't work?  (The xterm command does work).

Thanks for any advice,

Jenny

**C code from myT**
*(I have n processes with m threads each; each thread executes this code)*

```
pEnvRun_Now = EnvRun_Now;
pEnvRun_Now = getenv("RUN_NOW");
printf("RUN_NOW (string) = %s",pEnvRun_Now);
iRun_Now = atoi(pEnvRun_Now);
printf("RUN_NOW (int) = %d",iRun_Now);

while ( iRun_Now == 0){
    sleep(1);
    pEnvRun_Now = getenv("RUN_NOW");
    printf("RUN_NOW (string) = %s\n",pEnvRun_Now);
    iRun_Now = atoi(pEnvRun_Now);
    printf("RUN_NOW (int) = %d\n",iRun_Now);
}
```

**Bash script**

```
    else
        export RUN_NOW=0
        echo "RUN_NOW = $RUN_NOW"
        Num_Procs=$1
        Num_Threads=$2
        Elapsed_Secs=60
        Priority=$3
        echo "Num_Threads = $Num_Threads"
        echo "Elapsed_Secs = $Elapsed_Secs"
        echo "Priority = $Priority"
        if [[ $4 -eq 0 ]]; 
        then
            echo "Schedule $4 = FIFO"
        else
            echo "Schedule $4 = Round Robin "
        fi
        for (( i = 0; i < $Num_Procs; i++ )); do
            xterm -e ./myT "$Num_Threads" "$Elapsed_Secs" "$Priority" "$4" &
            gnome-terminal -x sh -c  ./myT "$Num_Threads" "$Elapsed_Secs" "$Priority" "$4" &
            gnome-terminal -x sh -c  "./myT $Num_Threads $Elapsed_Secs $Priority $4" &
        done
        export RUN_NOW=1
        echo "RUN_NOW = $RUN_NOW"
        wait
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For the environment part, I believe the sub shell gets a copy of the environment.  It's sort of "pass by value" not "pass by reference."  Once the environment is handed to the child, they don't cross paths any more.  The parent doesn't reach into the child anymore and the child cannot affect the parent.